# How can I determine if a unicode codepoint is alphabetic without a lookup table?

Tags: unicode, ocaml

I want to write a function in OCaml that determines whether an `int` represents a Unicode code point that is alphabetic. This is the only character class that I care about, because I'm writing a parser for a programming language and that is the only character class I am going to use. Is there a set of simple ranges that can determine whether or not a character is alphabetic? I've tried looking up the implementation of `java.lang.Character.isAlphabetic(int)` but they end up doing a lookup table, since they support many different Unicode properties.

Comment: Are you okay with using a library that may use a lookup table internally? There is [Uucp](http://erratique.ch/software/uucp).

Comment: Definitely use `uucp`. Daniel Bünzli (its author) is very thorough. There's no reason for you to reproduce his work.

Comment: I'd prefer a few lines of code with no deps, but I'll look at Uucp, thanks!

Comment: It's not possible to do this in "a few lines of code" as there are ~800 distinct code point ranges (covering over 110,000 characters) that have the "alphabetic" property in Unicode.

Comment: Heh. I'd just discovered this actually. I wrote a Java program to generate the OCAML code. It's... really something.